# How to force this.gridOption.getRowStyle function forcefully?

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have a ag-grid, which lets the user update the data. Once the data is updated, it hits the API and I receive the response back. Based upon the response I color the rows e.g if user updated row number 2 & 5 and response is Error for row 2 and Success for row 5, i color row 2 as Red and row 5 as Green.
I'm using getRowStyle function, but it seems it runs only once when the grid is loaded or it is edited. How do I force run this function so that row colors are loaded.

```
successArray = [5];

this.searchGridOption.getRowStyle = params => {

      if (this.successArray.includes(params.node.rowIndex)) {
        return { background: "green" };
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of reading and trying I could get done what i wanted.

this.gridApi.redrawRows();

is all needed to color the rows.

Answer (score 0):

May be `rowClassRules` is better suited for your requirement.

```
gridOptions.rowClassRules: {
  // apply green to success row
  'success-green': function(params) {
    return (this.successArray.includes(params.node.rowIndex));
  },

  // apply red to error row
  'error-red': function(params) { 
    return (this.errorArray.includes(params.node.rowIndex));
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried it and it seems my project is not picking up css classes. done everything.